# Displaying folders project

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, directory

for a couple of days now I have a problem with a project in ASP.NET. I should design a website which would:

- First: a function which would check if in folders in the project is a subfolder bin and in this bin folder if there are either one of two specific files
- Second: a function (List) which would display on the website only the folders which have the conditions of the first function

Now to the problem. With some help I managed to write the code (I'm a total newbie with ASP.NET btw). Here's the code:

Here the aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestSite.Home" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ListView ID="listView" runat="server"> 
        <ItemTemplate> 
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="<%#Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" /> 
        </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the aspx.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

namespace TestSite
{
public partial class WorkingwithDirectory : System.Web.UI.Page
{           
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    public bool IsApplicationDirectory( string directory )
    {
        if ( Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/../bin")) ) {
            if ( File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/../bin/Portal.Server.dll")) || File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/../bin/Host.Server.dll")) ) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public List<string> GetApplicationDirectories()
    {


        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/"));
        foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            if ( IsApplicationDirectory( dir.FullName ) ) 
            {
                results.Add(dir.FullName);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {

        if ( !Page.IsPostBack ) 
        {
            List<string> appDirectories = GetApplicationDirectories();

            --> listView.DataSource = appDirectories;
            --> listView.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem: Above in the aspx.cs file (where I gave the arrows) I get an error telling me: "The name 'listView' does not exist in the current context"

I tried out some solutions but unfortunetly none of theme worked. I would be more then thankfull for help.

Comment: `CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestSite.Home"`

Comment: `public partial class WorkingwithDirectory : System.Web.UI.Page`

Answer (score 0):

Rename

```
public partial class WorkingwithDirectory : System.Web.UI.Page
```

to

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunatly I get an exception while debuging my code:
"HttpException was unhandled by user code"
Is it possible that in the Server.MapPath part where i check if there is a subfolder bin and either of two files I went too deep with the path ??

Comment: Ok I changed also the Server.MapPath paths and still nothing. No matter what I do I can't get any folders displayed :(